# initial Value for observable not binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have my view model as:

```
class MyViewModel{
    Prop1 = ko.observable("Init");
    ...
 }

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

in my view:

```
@model Mod

<ul>
  @foreach(var item in Mod.Items)
  {
    <li>
     <a data-bind="click: function (){ Myfunc('@item.PropW')}, css: {active: Prop1() == '@item.PropW'}"></li>
  }
</ul>
```

even though I have `item` with `item.PropW` == `Init`, no list item become initially active, but as I start to click things work out great.Am I setting my initial value the wrong way?

Comment: What is the syntax you are using in your view?

Comment: @CaseyWebb I’m using razor in my view

Comment: it appears `Prop1()` is initially `null` not `"Init"`. `Prop1 = ko.observable("Init");` is ignored.

Comment: Unless you're using TypeScript, that is not valid syntax. You need to create it in the constructor, like so...

`class MyViewModel { constructor() { this.Prop1 = ko.observable("Init"); } }`